# Heat and temperature

Tags: heat-conduction

If a body goes to the deep space then what is the temperature of that body?

At that point of space is colder than the body, then the body also maintain temperature if not then what will be happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep space is everywhere bathed in microwave radiation that is left over from the Big Bang. If you place a chunk of material in deep space, it will absorb that radiation and re-radiate it away into space. After a while, the rate of absorption equals the rate of re-radiation and the temperature of the chunk of material will equal the effective temperature of the radiation. This equilibrium temperature is very cold: 2.7 degrees kelvin.

Comment: the equilibrium temperature of space is pretty cold then the whole universe is just like a closed box because we consider a example of earth ,earth also have a some equilibrium temperature.

Comment: My consideration is true or false?

Comment: By energy conservation laws , everything's energy is constant then space energy (heat) is constant?

Comment: the temperature of the microwave background is falling very slowly as the universe expands. energy is conserved.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the temperature of that body will be the temperature it was at before it entered deep space.

But because deep space is very cold and assuming the body's initial temperature was higher, the laws of thermodynamics now demand that the body cools down until its temperature is equal to that of deep space.

As deep space is also a deep vacuum, heat transfer via convection is difficult here. Heat transfer proceeds mostly via radiative loss (see [Stefan Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)) by the body and internal heat conduction.

Comment: why space is very cold?

Comment: In deep space, locations are very, very far removed from any heat sources (stars).

Comment: whole space have stable temperature ?

Comment: By energy conservation law , everything energy is constant then the space have also some temperature?

Comment: Yes but it's is like pouring some boiling water on the Earth. The water cools down and the Earth heats up. But the Earth is almost infinitely larger than that bit of water, so the heating up of the Earth is infinitesimally small.

Comment: boiling water cools down because for maintaining the  temperature of earth by convention.then in case space have similar to that example?

Comment: The point is that deep space is *vast* compared to almost anything in it. A hot object cooling in it will not affect its temperature.

Answer (score 1):

In a vacuum, where there is nothing to conduct heat, an object will lose or gain heat through radiation. With no internal source of heat production it will lose or gain heat until the heat radiation it absorbs is equal to the heat it radiates. In deep space far from any star it will become very cold. Closer to a star it will become warmer.